# Per file disk usage statistics C#

Tags: c#, performance, file-io, disk-io

Previously, a duplicate was suggested that explains per-process statistics but not per-file which I need. After days searching I can't find any specific way to get Per file disk stats.

I'm writing a PerfMonitor and want it to show which file has the expansive ReadWrite Operation.
Much like this:
[image: Disk Usage Per File]
(Windows Performance Monitor)

I tried all PerfCounters including a deep WMI search, but all only give numbers of the entire FileSystem or 'One number for whole process'.

I tried to list for each process its Files Handles then get some info this way, but can't find any way to get this statistics from file handles.

I read somewhere to Hook each process to count all ReadWrite bytes, but hook the entire system do not look simple and/or efficient

Hopelessness I used a disassembler to look which functions was the Windows PerfMon using but again I got nothing.

Someone have heard something that could help me?

Thanks in advance.